# Flutter like_button animation lags on tap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/like_button version like_button: ^1.0.4.

```
LikeButton(
        onTap: (value) {
          onGroupVotePress(document);
          return Future.value(!value);
        },
      ),
```

When I'm running my `onGroupVotePress` function my like_button animation crashes.

```
void onGroupVotePress(DocumentSnapshot document) {
      Network().appendToGroupList(document.id);
      Network().appendToGroupList(document.id);
  }
```

My `appendToGroupList` function is a simple firestore update:

```
Future appendToGroupList(String groupId, String field, List list) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .doc(groupId)
        .update({field: FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)});
  }
```

[image]

Why adding a simple void function to onTap case the like_button to lag?

Also how can I run code after the like_button onTap finished?

Thanks.

Comment: is that debug build or release build?

Comment: It's a release build

Comment: Some times animation will depend on mobile devices.

Comment: It's not that case since if I remove my `onGroupVotePress` function - everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```dart
LikeButton(
  onTap: (value) async {
    await onGroupVotePress(document);
    return !value;
  },
),
```

```dart
Future<void> onGroupVotePress(DocumentSnapshot document) async {
  await Network().appendToGroupList(document.id);
  await Network().appendToGroupList(document.id);
}
```

```dart
Future<void> appendToGroupList(String groupId, String field, List list) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups').doc(groupId).update({
    field: FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey @Rehmat thanks for helping. It did work! But I don't want to use `await`. Do you think there is another way?

Comment: Can I run any code after the liked_button performs?

Comment: There is no such function provided, but you can modify the code of this package and add your functionality.